# bootstrap CSS and JS not loading on heroku

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I made a chatroom with Node.JS and Socket.io. I'm using bootstrap CSS and JS in my project for things like tabs and carouser. The website looks and works perfect on my local server, here aresome screenshots:

[image: lading page]

[image: photos page]

but when I pushed the same code on my github and deployed it on heroku, every thing is just cluttered: https://doclerchat.herokuapp.com/

Here is the source code on GitHub: https://github.com/anshul119/chatapp/

Seems like Bootstrap CSS and JS aren't loading thats why only those specific things are creating problems. How can I resolve this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey brother, did you check your browser's console? [My browser's console renders this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4aum5hb3jcj0dii/sdsdsddd.JPG?dl=0). 

In `index.html` try have a reference to Bootstrap in the Heroku app space (i.e. `js/bootstrap.min.js` etc) rather than using a remote resource.

Comment: Try changing your requests to the CDN from **http** to **https**: `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css` and `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: Thank you @vanburen adding https solved the issue!

Comment: Hey @RichardKennethNiescior yes then it would work but I wanted to make it work with CDN only. the problem is solved by replacing "http" with "https"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as @vanburen commented, this solved the problem:

Change your requests to the CDN from http to https: 
`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstra‌​p.min.css` and `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap‌​.min.js`

Comment: how to use it? in reactjs?