# Button Shows on local file, but not when deployed on the web in heroku

Tags: javascript, html, css, heroku

I have a Bootstrap button. When the HTML file is run locally, it works, but when I open it on a browser it's not showing up. Can anyone please help?

```html
<form class="form-post">
  <select class="form-control" id="type" required autofocus>
    <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;"
      >Choose a subject category</option
    >
    <option value="">Textbook</option>
    <option value="">Course Notes</option>
    <option value="appliance">Electronics</option>
    <option value="appliance">iClicker</option>
    <option value="appliance">Calculator</option>
    <option value="appliance">Others</option>
  </select>

  <button id="post2" class="post-ad" type="submit">Post Your Ad h</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have, but have you included the bootstrap link(s)? I used it a while ago, but I remember using them, you can check them out [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/).

Also, you can check the examples [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/), thereare buttons, radio, checkbox, and more.

Also, I found a similar question, that maybe could actually help you more than my past answer. the answer is in the comment made by vanburen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713780/bootstrap-css-and-js-not-loading-on-heroku)

Answer (score 1):

Copy-paste the stylesheet  into your  before all other stylesheets to load our CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Change

```
 <button id="post2" class="post-ad" type="submit" >Post Your Ad h</button>
```

to

```
<button id="post2" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Post Your Ad h</button>
```